# How do you determine which 4 pixels to interpolate, using bilinear interpolation?

Tags: 2d, image, interpolation

I read about bilinear interpolation on Wikipedia and many sources, but I still don't understand how do you determine which four pixels to interpolate.

For example, if I have 5 pixels(y=0), do I interpolate pixel 1 with pixel 2, pixel 3 with pixel 4, but how about pixel 5? Do I interpolate pixel 5 or not? All the examples shown to me are all perfect quads of 2x2.

Answer (score 2):

Conventionally, the pixels (or "texels") in a texture are arranged in a 2D grid. Let's say it looks like this:

```
↑
2   I   J   K   L
|
1   E   F   G   H
|
0   A   B   C   D

    0---1---2---3---→
```

Here I've laid out 12 texels labelled A-L on two coordinate axes, starting at 0,0 in the bottom left-hand corner and increasing by 1 for each texel to the right or above.

For simplicity, I've located the texels themselves at the integer corner points of this lattice, but note that in some contexts the texels are treated as sitting in the centers of each square. You can subtract 0.5 from each coordinate to convert back to integer points.

We can use this coordinate system to specify our sampling location within this grid. For instance, sampling the point (2, 1) would get us 100% the value of texel G.

But our sampling point can also have a fractional component. I could sample from the point (1.7, 0.2). Flooring to the closest integer below, that means the bottom-left of our 2x2 sampling block will be texel B, but we'll also want to blend in the texels right and above that: F, G, and C. So the 2x2 block we're in looks like:

```
F     G

    .    ← sample point somewhere near here
B     C
```

We can get the bilinear blending weights from the fractional component of our sample coordinate. 1.7 has a fractional component of 0.7, which means we want 70% of the value of the texel to the right, and 30% of the value of the texel to the left.

In the top row of our sampling quad, that's

```
Lerp(F, G, 0.7)
```

And in the bottom row it's

```
Lerp(B, C, 0.7)
```

The fractional component of the vertical coordinate gives us the blending weight between these two lerps:

```
Lerp(
   Lerp(B, C, 0.7),
   Lerp(F, G, 0.7),
   0.2
)
```

In the event that you have just a single row of texels, then "bilinear interpolation" really reduces to just "linear interpolation" or a single lerp between the two texels left and right of your sample position. There are no texel value differences on the vertical axis, so you don't need a nested outer lerp at all. (Or you could consider that the single row repeats infinitely above and below, and apply bilinear interpolation that reads the two left & right texels twice each)

```
A   B • C   D
```

Sampling this row at (1.5, 0.1) would give you:

```
Lerp( 
    Lerp(B, C, 0.5),
    Lerp(B, C, 0.5),
    0.1
)
```

...which is the same as just `Lerp(B, C, 0.5)` (any interpolation of a value with itself just returns itself)